# Join with adding new row

Tags: postgresql

I have a query which returns next table with name first_table:

| Name | ID |
| --- | --- |
| First | 1 |
| Second | 2 |

And I need to join another table named second_table:

| ID | ParentID |
| --- | --- |
| 22 | 1 |
| 33 | 323 |

By the columns first_table."ID" = second_table."ParentID", so if first_table_id exists, I need to add one more row with its first_table."Name" value

So the result should be:

| Name | ID |
| --- | --- |
| First | 1 |
| First | 22 |
| Second | 2 |

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this ([result here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/suBGaoZHs5HXccBs3vF9hS/0))

```
select t1.name,t1.id
from t1 join t2 on t1.id = t2.parent_id
union
select t1.name,t2.id
from t1 join t2 on t1.id = t2.parent_id
union
select t1.name,t1.id
from t1 
where t1.id not in (select parent_id from t2)
order by name,id
```